# What is the best way to express this situation

Tags: meaning

Dears,

I always experience this situation but I don't exactly know how to express my self, I tried to find an answer in the dictionary but unfortunately I didn't find anything that suits the case.

A lot of times we get answers from people but the answer is not of what we want. what is the verb that can be used in this situation.

It's not acceptable -- I don't think this gonna be work cause it's when someone did something badly wrong.

It's not rational ??

What is the most suitable word ? I Hope only native speakers answer my question.

Thanks to your answers and replies in advance

Comment: Maybe what we require is not help from people who may know more words but less about what we need than we do, but a better method of seeking what we need.

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you are looking for is

> **Satisfactory**
>
> 1. giving or affording satisfaction; fulfilling
>    all demands or requirements: a satisfactory solution.
> 2. Theology.
>    atoning or expiating.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/satisfactory